# Change Colors of button inside AlertController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactionsheet

I want to have different text color for different button inside ActionSheet 
I found following code which change the text color of all button but in my case i want to have different color for every button

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_alertController");
if ([actionSheet respondsToSelector:selector])
{

    UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];


    if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
    {
        alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
else
{
    // use other methods for iOS 7 or older.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not doable without using private API.

Comment: what are the consequences of using private API, and how to use that ?

Comment: Consequences are that your app will most probably be refused on the App Store by Apple as they explicitly forbid usage of private API and will verify that no private API call is made during review.

Comment: ok thanks for the info